# ggplot2 aes_string() fails to handle names starting with numbers or containing spaces

Tags: r, ggplot2

If the column names of a `data.frame` are started with numbers, or have spaces, `aes_string()` fails to handle them:

```
foo=data.frame("1st Col"=1:5, "2nd Col"=5:1, check.names=F)
bar=colnames(foo)
ggplot(foo, aes_string(x=bar[1],y=bar[2])) + geom_point()
# Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:2: unexpected symbol
# 1: 1st
#     ^

foo=data.frame("First Col"=1:5, "Second Col"=5:1, check.names=F)
bar=colnames(foo)
ggplot(foo, aes_string(x=bar[1],y=bar[2])) + geom_point()
# Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:7: unexpected symbol
# 1: First Col
#          ^

foo=data.frame("First_Col"=1:5, "Second_Col"=5:1, check.names=F)
bar=colnames(foo)
ggplot(foo, aes_string(x=bar[1],y=bar[2]))+geom_point()
# Now it works
```

[image]

Is there any way to have spaces in the column names, or they are started with numbers, and we can use them in ggplot2? Please consider we might don't know the column name, so please avoid to provide examples with constant column names - something like below:

```
aes_string(x=`1st Col`, y=`2nd Col`)
```

Comment: try using backticks to enclose your strings (I'm not sure they'll come through in comments: "``"  (Actually, taking a closer look I'm not sure that will work).  It feels like it's going to be quite hard to jump through this particular hoop, I would use "legal" column names and use `labs()` or other approaches to change the axis labels etc.

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks, but as I mentioned in the question I am not looking for the case that we already know the column names, as constants. Do you have any idea when they are variables?

Comment: It's the second part of my question: I think it's hard and that the more idiomatic thing to do is to use legal column names and adjust the guide labels accordingly.  It would be nice if `ggplot` (and more of R generally) worked in conjunction with the `rms` package's `label()` framework ...

Comment: Are there always two columns?

Comment: You have to use `aes_string(x="`1st Col`", y="`2nd Col`")` - otherwise `aes_string` wouldn't be able to replicate (e.g.) `aes(x + 1)`

Comment: @hadley Thank you. Can we do something similar in `facet_grid()` ?

Comment: @hadley Actually I mean `facet_grid_string()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this method should work programmatically:

```
foo=data.frame("1st Col"=1:5, "2nd Col"=5:1, check.names=F)

#Save the colnames
bar=colnames(foo)

#change the names to something usable
names(foo) <- c("col1", "col2")

#Plot with arbitrary labs
ggplot(foo, aes(x=col1, y=col2)) + geom_point()+
  labs(x=bar[1], y=bar[2])
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The original question asked how to modify a value of a variable so it is acceptable to ggplot() when the value is not know beforehand.

Write a function that adds back-ticks to the beginning and end of the value of the variable:

```
# ggName -> changes a string so it is enclosed in back-ticks.
#   This can be used to make column names that have spaces (blanks)
#   or non-letter characters acceptable to ggplot2.
#   This version of the function is vectorized with sapply.
ggname <- function(x) {
    if (class(x) != "character") {
        return(x)
    }
    y <- sapply(x, function(s) {
        if (!grepl("^`", s)) {
            s <- paste("`", s, sep="", collapse="")
        }
        if (!grepl("`$", s)) {
            s <- paste(s, "`", sep="", collapse="")
        }
    }
    )
    y 
}
```

Examples:

```
ggname(12)
```

[1] 12

```
ggname("awk ward")
```

"`awk ward`"

```
l <- c("awk ward", "no way!")
ggname(l)
```

"`awk ward`"  "`no way!`"

Comment: Thanks! For my purposes, I used a simplified version: ```paste("`", x, "`", sep="")```.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function `aes_string2` below instead of `aes_string`:

```
aes_string2 <- function(...){
  args <- lapply(list(...), function(x) sprintf("`%s`", x))
  do.call(aes_string, args)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation and I used `` to make it understand:

```
mydf$ROIs <- row.names(mydf)
df.long <- melt(mydf)
colnames(df.long)[3] <- "Methods"
colnames(df.long)[4] <- "Mean L2 Norm Error"
variable.name="Variable", na.rm=TRUE)
ggplot(df.long, aes(ROIs, `Mean L2 Norm Error`, fill=Methods))+  
geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,hjust=1,vjust=1))
```

Comment: For what it's worth the OP said explicitly that they were *not* interested in solutions using backticks to protect names that were known at coding time: "Please consider we might don't know the column name, so please avoid to provide examples with constant column names - something like below ..."

Comment: I used `" "` and the code ran without errors but the values were not plotted so I had to change the column names without space and then the values got plotted.