# ggplot2: how to plot columns containing special characters?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to create a plot for a data frame, the column names of which contain special characters. Consider the following example:

```
f <- data.frame(foo=c(1, 2, 3), bar=c(4, 5, 6))
# The following line works fine
ggplot(f) + geom_point(aes_string(x="foo", y="bar"))
names(f) <- c("foo", "bar->baz")
# The following also works, but seems not elegant
ggplot(f) + geom_line(aes(x=foo, y=f[,"bar->baz"])) 
# I'd like something like the following, but this doesn't work.
ggplot(f) + geom_line(aes_string(x="foo", y="bar->baz"))
```

The output of the last command is:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'bar' not found
```

Does anybody know a way of creating this plot? Or is this simply a [limitation of ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445435/ggplot2-aes-string-fails-to-handle-names-starting-with-numbers-or-containing-s)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should add  backquotes `` like this:

```
ggplot(f) + geom_line(aes_string(x="foo", y="`bar->baz`"))
```

Or

```
ggplot(f) + geom_line(aes(x=foo, y=`bar->baz`))
```

Answer (score 0):

param <- 'TEST+'

testParam <- paste('`',param,'`',sep="")

plot1 <- ggplot(dataset, aes_string(x = testParam ))