# How can I change the column name passed to "fill" programmatically?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot an area stack chart where the fill can be changed programmatically by changing a "string holder" variable. Here is an example of what I'd like to do.

```
this_group_label <- "Roots & Tubers"
#[...lots of code in which a data frame df_plot is created with a column named "Roots & Tubers...]"
gg <- ggplot(df_plot, aes(x = year, y = `Pctge CC`, fill = this_group_label))
gg <- gg + geom_area(position = "stack")
gg
```

So that I could then change the string stored in `this_group_label` when dealing with a new data frame with a different column name.

I have tried `aes_string()`

```
this_group_label <- "Roots & Tubers"
#[...lots of code in which a data frame df_plot is created with a column named "Roots & Tubers...]"
gg <- ggplot(df_plot, aes_string("year", "`Pctge CC`", fill = this_group_label))
gg <- gg + geom_area(position = "stack")
gg
```

and `get()`

```
this_group_label <- "Roots & Tubers"
#[...lots of code in which a data frame df_plot is created with a column named "Roots & Tubers...]"
gg <- ggplot(df_plot, aes(x = year, y = `Pctge CC`, fill = get(this_group_label)))
gg <- gg + geom_area(position = "stack")
gg
```

to no avail. When I try these last two I am getting the error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Roots' not found`

Comment: Don't use backticks in the `aes_string` version, just do `y = "Pctge CC"`.

Comment: @Gregor Implemented your correction, still getting error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Roots' not found`

Comment: See @hadley's comment in this issue: [aes_string fails with space in column name](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2447). Dupe-oid: [ggplot2 aes_string() fails to handle names starting with numbers or containing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445435/ggplot2-aes-string-fails-to-handle-names-starting-with-numbers-or-containing-s). [Adding space in the variable names with aes_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061184/adding-space-in-the-variable-names-with-aes-string)

Comment: [Using ggplot2 with columns that have spaces in their names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133567/using-ggplot2-with-columns-that-have-spaces-in-their-names)

Comment: In addition: please post a _minimal reproducible example_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ggplot2 with columns that have spaces in their names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133567/using-ggplot2-with-columns-that-have-spaces-in-their-names)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
this_group_label <- "Roots & Tubers"
#[...lots of code in which a data frame df_plot is created with a column named "Roots & Tubers...]"
fill_label <- paste0("`", this_group_label, "`")
gg <- ggplot(df_plot, aes_string("year", "`Pctge CC`", fill = fill_label))
gg <- gg + geom_area(position = "stack")
gg
```

Note the backticks around `Pctge CC` are also necessary for this to work.

Comment: This will fail if your `fill_label` value contains spaces. To fix it, you need to use a little detour: `deparse(as.name(fill_label), backtick = TRUE)` (note that the naïve solution, putting backticks around the string, may also fail).

Comment: @KonradRudolph `this_group_label` has spaces, but then this is fixed by the admittedly naive and amateurish `paste0("`", this_group_label, "`")` trick. Given this trick, `fill_label` will never contain spaces.

Comment: Right, I overlooked that. But as mentioned I think that could fail (not for simple spaces though). A more robust and more descriptive way is at any rate shown in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

`rlang::sym` takes a string and converts it to a symbol. You just need to [unquote](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html) it using `!!`, because `aes` expects unevaluated expressions:

```
library(rlang)

gg <- ggplot( df_plot, aes(x=year, y=`Pctge CC`, fill = !!sym(this_group_label)) )
gg <- gg + geom_area(position = "stack")
gg
```